# Google App Engine: User is null

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to create a backend and JavaScript client using Google Cloud Endpoints. User authorization works fine through API explorer and on backend 'user' object is populated. However when similar call is made from JavaScript client, 'user' is null on backend. On client side user is authorized and access token is also valid.

Please let me know if there is any known issue from Google App Engine or any fix available.

Comment: You should post your code here.

Comment: is this in the cloud, or running on development server?

Comment: Please read the faq on how to post here. For one wheres the code??

Answer (score 1):

Check that the scopes you request with the `Javascript Client Library` reflect the scopes that you require in your `Cloud Enpoints API`.

**index.js**

```
gapi.auth.authorize({
    client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    immediate: true //This is optional
}, callback);
```

**Endpoint.java**

```
@Api(
    name = "ENDPOINT_NAME",
    clientIds = {
        com.google.api.server.spi.Constant.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID,
        'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
    }
    scopes = {"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"},
)
```